# Why doesn't the regex match when I add groups?

Tags: python, regex

I have this regex code in python :

```
if re.search(r"\{\\fad|fade\(\d{1,4},\d{1,4}\)\}", text):
  print(re.search(r"\{\\fad|fade\((\d{1,4}),(\d{1,4})\)\}", text).groups())
```

`text` is `{\fad(200,200)}Épisode 101 : {\i1}The Ghost{\i0}\Nv. 1.03` and read from a file (don't know if that helps).

This returns the following:

```
(None, None)
```

When I change the regex in the print to `r"\{\\fad\((\d{1,4}),(\d{1,4})\)\}"`, it returns the correct values:

```
(200, 200)
```

Can anyone see why the conditional `fad|fade` matches the regex in the `re.search` but doesn't return the correct values of the groups in the print?

Thanks.

Comment: I would consider revising your title such that it's more searchable,

Comment: Either I'm missing the point of the question, or everyone answering is. Isn't the real question "Why doesn't the regex match when I add groups?"

Comment: Title changed. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put extra parens around the choice: `re.search(r"{(?:\\fad|fade)\((\d{1,4}),(\d{1,4})\)}", text).groups()`

Also, escaping `{}` braces isn't necessary, it just needlessly clutters your regexp.

Comment: It works but I don't understand the "(?:" could you clarify, please?

Comment: @dex: It's a non-capturing group, so it won't show up when you print the groups.

Answer (score 4):

The bracket is part of the or branch starting with fade, so it's looking for either "{fad" or "fade(...".  You need to group the fad|fade part together.  Try:

```
r"\{\\(?:fad|fade)\(\d{1,4},\d{1,4}\)\}"
```

**[Edit]**
The reason you do get into the if block is because the regex **is** matching, but only because it detects it starts with "{\fad".  However, that part of the match contains no groups.  You need to match with the part that defines the groups if you want to capture them.

Comment: That was my first guess too, but then why does the first regex match?

Comment: The first doesn't match because | has no idea how far back or forward to look, so it looks back to the beginning, and forward to (.

Comment: @David Berger: I actually commented on the question to say almost exactly that (and suggest a non-capturing group), but then I realized that I had no idea why that would still let the first regex match, so I deleted it. Thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
r"\{\\fade?\(\d{1,4},\d{1,4}\)\}"
```

Comment: Certainly a more elegant expression, but doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: It fixes the heart of the problem.  I think \d{1,4} should still be grouped for capture.

Comment: It's matching "{\fad", so the search works but doesn't capture the numbers

Answer (score 1):

I think your conditional is looking for "\fad" or "fade", I think you need to move a \ outside the grouping if you want to look for "\fad" or "\fade".

Comment: And if I want to look for "fad" or "fade"? Is there a way without grouping it like (fad|fade)? I mean, I don't want it to be found when calling .groups(). I just want the others values.

Comment: Yes, but I think others have already given the correct examples so I'll quit while I'm up... regex's are a minefield:-)

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
r"\{\\fade?\((\d{1,4}),(\d{1,4})\)\}"
```

The `e?` is an optional `e`.
The way you have it now matches `{\fad` or `fade(0000,0000)}`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the python dialect of regular expressions, but wouldn't you need to 'group' the "fad|fade" somehow to make sure it isn't trying to find "fad OR fade(etc..."?